# ImportError: cannot import name 'relu6' and AttributeError: module 'keras.applications.mobilenet' has no attribute 'relu6'

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to convert a h5 keras model to a `.mlmodel` file type, using this code:

```
from keras.models import load_model
import keras
from keras.applications.mobilenet import MobileNet
from keras.layers import DepthwiseConv2D
# convert the model to coreml format
print("[INFO] converting model")

from keras.utils.generic_utils import CustomObjectScope

with CustomObjectScope({'relu6': keras.applications.mobilenet.relu6,'DepthwiseConv2D':     keras.applications.mobilenet.DepthwiseConv2D}):
   model = load_model('/Users/nikhil.c/aslModel.h5', custom_objects={
               'relu6': MobileNet})
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert("/Users/nikhil.c        /aslModel.h5",
        input_names="image",
        image_input_names="image",
        image_scale=1/255.0,
        class_labels= ["hello", "hi", "you"],
        is_bgr=True)

# save the model to disk
coremltools.utils.save_spec(coreml_model, 'aslModel.mlmodel')
```

I have received this error initially before using `CustomObjectScope`:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'relu6'
```

I fixed it through `CustomObjectScope`, but now I am getting the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'keras.applications.mobilenet' has no attribute 'relu6'.
```

I do not usually post in stack overflow, so please tell me if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have is for an older Keras version, the latest Keras I checked (2.2.2) has the ReLU and DepthWiseConv2D already integrated inside `keras.layers`, so you only need to impor this to use MobileNet:

```
import keras
from keras.applications import MobileNet
```

There is also `MobileNetV2` in the same package for a newer version of MobileNet.