# Core ML coremltools AttributeError: module 'keras.applications.mobilenet' has no attribute 'relu6'

Tags: keras, coremltools, relu

We are trying to convert a .h5 Keras model into a .mlmodel model, my code is as follows:

```
from keras.models import load_model
import keras
from keras.applications import MobileNet
from keras.layers import DepthwiseConv2D

from keras.utils.generic_utils import CustomObjectScope

with CustomObjectScope({'relu6': keras.applications.mobilenet.relu6,'DepthwiseConv2D': keras.applications.mobilenet.DepthwiseConv2D}):
    model = load_model('CNN_tourist_11.h5', custom_objects={'relu6': MobileNet})

output_labels = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert("CNN_tourist_11.h5",
                                                    input_names="image",
                                                    image_input_names="image",
                                                    class_labels= output_labels,)

coremltools.utils.save_spec(coreml_model, 'place10.mlmodel')
```

We look up for the similiar question posed 6 days ago, and we also imported the MobileNet, but it still showing this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'keras.applications.mobilenet' has no attribute 'relu6'
```

My Tensorflow version is 1.10.0
and Keras version is 2.2.2

We will really appreciate if anyone can give us advice about why it keeps showing this error, thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: cannot import name 'relu6' and AttributeError: module 'keras.applications.mobilenet' has no attribute 'relu6'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52632612/importerror-cannot-import-name-relu6-and-attributeerror-module-keras-applic)

Comment: This has already been answered before, please before asking a question, try searching for similar ones to see if the answer is already here.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I saw the question posed 6 days ago, and I did what you suggest "from keras.applications import MobileNet" but it still won't work. Sorry for the similar question, but I did look up for the question, thanks.

Comment: Then you need to be specific on what didn't work, add as more detail to your question as possible.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I have amended my question, and thank you for your reminder.

Comment: I think you didn't understand the answer, all this stuff with relu6 is no longer necessary, you don't need to import it or use a custom scope with it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In latest Keras versions, MobileNet's components have been integrated with the rest of Keras' layers, so they are not available anymore as parts of the mobilenet package. Then you need to change the code to:

```
from keras.models import load_model
import keras
from keras.applications import MobileNet
from keras.layers import DepthwiseConv2D

model = load_model('CNN_tourist_11.h5')

output_labels = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert("CNN_tourist_11.h5",
                                                    input_names="image",
                                                    image_input_names="image",
                                                    class_labels= output_labels,)

coremltools.utils.save_spec(coreml_model, 'place10.mlmodel')
```

Comment: I solved the problem by deleting the following two lines in keras/_layers2.py:
'from keras_applications.mobilenet import relu6' and 
'from keras.applications.mobilenet import DepthwiseConv2D, relu6'

but after if I got an other problem:
 'MLModel' object has no attribute 'SerializeToString'
ha ha, but thanks for your help.

Comment: My Keras version is 2.2.4, tensorflow 1.10.0, and still facing the same issue, can anybody help?

Comment: @KFZ Please make your own question, it is not clear what "the same issue" is at all.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro It ths SAME ISSUE literally, word by word, compared to this question. The only difference is the version that I mentioned. If I make another question, you'd say please don't ask duplicate questions.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro BTW, the solution you provided doesn't work at all for both me and the guy who asked the question, he's just polite.

Comment: @KFZ You cannot be getting the same error message with the code in this answer because its not importing relu6, that is why I just don't believe you. I tell you to ask your own question because you might think its the same issue, but I don't think it is. The details matter. Or are you talking about the error 'MLModel' object has no attribute 'SerializeToString'?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro It's exactly the 'relu6' problem. Please don't be so arrogant with what you believe or think, please RESPECT and read other people's words even if you think you know a lot.

Comment: @KFZ Its not about what I believe, it is about what I can see, you just tell me its the same problem, and I have to be skeptic because you haven't provided additional information or code that reproduces the problem. You cannot get an import error about relu6 if you aren't importing relu6 at all, which is my answer does. You could be getting a different error surely. Also remember that you are not entitled to an answer.

Comment: @KFZ  Matias Valdenegro is almost right, but if you type that code he paste it will ptintout "cannot import name 'relu6'", the only thing you have to do is to go to the Keras suit you installed, in the Keras file, there's a file name "_layers2.py". In "_layers2.py", delete 'from keras_applications.mobilenet import relu6' and 'from keras.applications.mobilenet import DepthwiseConv2D, relu6' , then the problem will be solved.

Comment: @Rex I see the problem, you keep looking at just the error message and not the full backtrace, the import is inside coremltools, I would have noticed that if you included the full backtrace. So its not the same problem as this is additional information. It seems that coremltools hasn't been updated to support Keras > 2.2.3

Comment: @KFZ I want to declare that I have great respect to Matias Valdenegro, and without his advice, my problem won't be solved. In my case(Keras 2.2.2), Matias Valdenegro is right that the ReLU and DepthWiseConv2D already integrated inside, but the file named "_layers2.py" in Keras suit still importing the "relu6", that's why it printout error. But my chase may not be exactly like yours, so just refer to it.

Comment: @Rex I've already made a PR to coremltools so they fix this issue: https://github.com/apple/coremltools/pull/260

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I'm not expecting an answer from you. I just expect discussing questions in a good manner. I mentioned not only once that my Keras version is 2.2.4, and you just ignored it and say, "you haven't provided any information, I don't believe you". You should learn how to communicate with others from Rex.

Comment: @Rex I understand all what you said and relax. Thank you for all the information you provided and that helps a lot.

Comment: @KFZ Keras version is not that relevant, a full traceback is.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro now that you admit it's not about Keras, let's quote what you told me: "You cannot be getting the same error message with the code in this answer because its not importing relu6, that is why I just don't believe you." Please be more cautious when you want to lesson others and make sure you test the code what you provided.

Comment: @KFZ Its on you to provide information about debugging a problem, not on me. Your attitude makes me just stop answering questions in this site.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro that's good news. Please, please be nice to people in other question sites, and again, remember to test your code before judging other people's words.

Comment: @KFZ Sure, blame me for trying to help you.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Wow, you were just trying to show you were right, and god thank you for not helping me in your way.

Answer (score 0):

I amended my code:

```
from keras.models import load_model
import keras
from keras.applications import MobileNet
from keras.layers import DepthwiseConv2D

#from keras.utils.generic_utils import CustomObjectScope

#with CustomObjectScope({'relu6': keras.applications.mobilenet.relu6,'DepthwiseConv2D': keras.applications.mobilenet.DepthwiseConv2D}):
    #model = load_model('CNN_tourist_11.h5', custom_objects={'relu6': MobileNet})

output_labels = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert("CNN_tourist_11.h5",
                                                    input_names="image",
                                                    image_input_names="image",
                                                    class_labels= output_labels,)

coremltools.utils.save_spec(coreml_model, 'place10.mlmodel')
```

Some parts of the printout:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/coremltools/converters/keras/_layers2.py in <module>()
      8 if _keras.__version__ >= _StrictVersion('2.2.0'):
      9     from keras.layers import DepthwiseConv2D
---> 10     from keras_applications.mobilenet import relu6
     11 else:
     12     from keras.applications.mobilenet import DepthwiseConv2D, relu6

ImportError: cannot import name 'relu6'
```

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I amended my code, and here are the printouts

Answer (score 0):

Actually the question is answered by @Rex himself in the comments. I just want to make it clear and short as an "Answer" for people encountering the same issue.

This problem is not about keras, it's about coremltools. You need to find a`_layers2.py` in coremltools files and comment out `from keras_application.mobilenet import relu6`:

- Find `_layer2.py` at `[YOUR_PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR]/lib/python3.6/site-packages/coremltools/converters/keras/_layers2.py`
- Comment out the line like this:

  ```
  if _keras.__version__ >= _StrictVersion('2.2.0'):
      from keras.layers import DepthwiseConv2D
  # Modified by KF 10/16/2018
  #    from keras_applications.mobilenet import relu6
  else:
     from keras.applications.mobilenet import DepthwiseConv2D, relu6
  ```

Then, in your code, delete ALL import related to Keras, they are not relavant;

For the `'Sequential' object has no attribute 'SerializeToString'` error, use `coreml_model.save` instead of `tools.utils.save_spec()`.

```
# from keras.models import load_model
# import keras
# from keras.applications import MobileNet
# from keras.layers import DepthwiseConv2D

output_labels = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert("CNN_tourist_11.h5",
                                                input_names="image",
                                                image_input_names="image",
                                                class_labels= output_labels,)

#coremltools.utils.save_spec(coreml_model, 'place10.mlmodel')
coreml_model.save('place10.mlmodel')
```

Problem solved.